# Alternative to if..else statement

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a table in a database that contains a bunch of different controls. In my Page_Init method, I need to load the appropriate control based on a Session variable that is being passed in.  Is there any better way to do this then using a whole bunch of if..else statements?  I have about 15 to 20 different scenarios that are possible so I do not want to write 20 if..else statements.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

DataTable entitled "Value" with three columns:(ID, Name, Description):

```
ID | Name | Description
-------------------
 1 | A    | First   
 2 | B    | Second   
 3 | C    | Third
```

And here is my code:

```
ControlOne c1;
ControlTwo c2;
ControlThree c3;

protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataSet DS = Client.GetInformation(Session["Number"].ToString());
    DataRow DR = DS.Tables["Value"].Rows[0];

    if (DR["Name"].ToString() == "A" && DR["Description"].ToString() == "First")
    {
        c1 = (ControlOne)LoadControl("~/ControlOne.ascx");
        panel1.Controls.Add(c1);
    }
    else if (DR["Name"].ToString() == "B" && DR["Description"].ToString() == "Second")
    {
        c2 = (ControlTwo)LoadControl("~/ControlTwo.ascx");
        panel1.Controls.Add(c2);
    }
    else if (DR["Name"].ToString() == "C" && DR["Description"].ToString() == "Third")
    {
        c3 = (ControlThree)LoadControl("~/ControlThree.ascx");
        panel1.Controls.Add(c3);
    }
    else if... //lists more scenarios here..
}
```

Comment: You mean a switch statement?

Comment: Use a map of strings to types.

Comment: how about concatenating the string and use switch case.

Comment: Would it be possible to add another column to the table that has the control name and then just load the controls returned dynamically in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a switch statement.

However, there is a better way. Your example has ID, Name, Description in the DB table. So keep the name field the same as the usercontrol name and you can do this:

```
string controlName = dr["Name"];
c1 = LoadControl(string.Format("~/{0}.ascx", controlName));
panel1.Controls.Add(c1);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 7):

You can do something like this:

```
var controlsToLoad = new Dictionary<Tuple<string, string>, string>()
{
    { Tuple.Create("A", "First"), "~/ControlOne.ascx" },
    { Tuple.Create("B", "Second"), "~/ControlTwo.ascx" },
    { Tuple.Create("C", "Third"), "~/ControlThree.ascx" },
    ... 
};

var key = Tuple.Create(DR["Name"].ToString(), DR["Description"].ToString());
if (controlsToLoad.ContainsKey(key))
{
    Control c = LoadControl(controlsToLoad[key]);
    panel1.Controls.Add(c);
}
```

It's more compact and far more easy to read than a massive if..else or switch block.

Comment: Note that you'd probably want the dictionary to be a field, rather than a local, just because there's no need to re-create it on every single postback.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!  This is a very good idea and well thought out!

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that you could use a switch statement, and only test on either "Name" or "Description".